# Lambda reductions prove S K = K I

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus, proof-of-correctness, k-combinator, s-combinator

Hello I am having trouble proving these combinators S K = K I

The steps with the brackets [] are just telling you the step i am doing. For example [λxy.x / x] in λyz.x z(y z)  means I am about to substitute (λxy.x) for every x in the expression λyz.x z(y z)

what I have tried so far is reducing S K and I got this:

```
S K
(λxyz.x z(y z)) (λxy.x)
[λxy.x / x] in λyz.x z(y z) 
(λyz. (λxy.x) z(y z))
[z/x] in λy.x
(λyz. (λy.z) (y z))
[y/y] in λy.z
(λyz. z z)
```

and then reducing K I and I got this:

```
K I
(λxy.x) (λx.x)
[λx.x / x] in λy.x
λy. λx.x
```

though the two answers do not seem to be equal to me (λyz. z z) and λy. λx.x
can someone please explain to me what I did wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(λy.z) (y z)` reduces to just `z`, not `z z`, so `(λyz. (λy.z) (y z))` is `λyz. z`, which is the same as `λy. λx. x`.

Comment: Ah okay thank you! can you just explain why (λy.z) (y z) is reduced to just z? what happens the the second z?

Comment: In `(λy. z) (y z)`, the `(λy. z)` lambda is applied to the whole of `(y z)` (because it has parentheses around it), so it becomes `z[(y z)/y]`, but as there is no `y` in `z`, it remains just `z`.

Comment: okay thank you. I thought it was just the y that gets substituted in (λy. z) and the other z just is left over. Thanks for clearing that up.